# Java Eclipse Google App Engine Tutorial for Google Wallet

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, android-pay

I preface this with the fact I am a Java newbie. If one has a working web app in Java using Google App Engine, and one is looking for a simple tutorial for how to add Google Wallet to accomplish a pay-per-use requirement of that web site, does anyone have a reference for a very easy to understand tutorial, book, sample, etc.? What Google provides seems to be a jumble.

If it matters, here is a basic outline of what my web app currently does: User enters a little bit of basic data, chooses from some options, hits "submit", and a whole bunch of calculations happen, with a printout of the result. I would like a tutorial or any direction on how to have Google Wallet popup at the point of "submit" and the calculations happen when that process is complete. Nothing fancy.

Thank you in advance. ANY direction is appreciated. I do not need my hand held (although I won't refuse that), just need a good place to visit to get those hands dirty without slamming my head on the desk in utter confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the Google Wallet for digital goods API.
https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial

On submit you initiate the purchase flow.  Then on the success callback you do whatever calculations you need.